# How do i show V is a linear subspace if it's defined like this?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V =\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x+3y=3z\}$,and let $T :V \to \mathbb R^3$. be given by $T(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)\times(1,3,−3)$, the usual cross-product in $\mathbb R^3$.

How do i show that V is a linear subspace? I'm confused because I know this as a matrix.

Comment: What do you need to show is a linear subspace -- $V$ or $T(V)$?

Comment: I have to show V sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $V$ is a subspace, you have to show that for any vectors $u,v \in V$ and scalar $\alpha, \beta$, $\alpha u + \beta v \in V$ as well. (This is the definition, but in fact, showing that $\alpha u + v \in V$ turns out to be sufficient.)

So let $(a,b,c), (x,y,z) \in V$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and test whether $\alpha (a,b,c) + (x,y,z) \in V$, that is, whether it fulfils the definition given for $V$.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the result that for any linear map $A\colon X\to Y$ kernel $\ker V$ is subspace of $X$ then we have

$$V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\ |\ x + 3y - 3z = 0 \} = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\ |\ A(x,y,z) = 0 \} = \ker A\leq \mathbb R^3$$

where $A\colon\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ defined by $(x,y,z)\mapsto x + 3y -3z$ is a linear map. But, to verify that $A$ is linear is pretty much the same procedure as MissMonicaE described.